# class Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync() equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, azure, jwt, azure-functions, google-api-java-client

I have built an Azure Function App in C# & I am trying to figure out the equivalent of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync() in Java, as my client requires my code framework to be in a Java. I need to be able to return the Json Web Token (JWT) and call it into a return body within the function.

I have discovered that the Java class GoogleCredential is depreciated but some of Google's product documentation STILL refers to it: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.

Below is a snippet code of what I developed in C# but I cannot find any similar manner to call this class in Java:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

    var cred = GoogleCredential.FromJson(*[myjsonkey]*).CreateScoped(new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" });
    var token = await cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
```

The Java class, GoogleCredential is now depreciated entirely (here's the link: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential#com_google_api_client_googleapis_auth_oauth2_GoogleCredential_createDelegated_java_lang_String_)

Any advice or examples of how I can mimic the same use of GoogleCredential class equivalent in Java to return the JWT would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I understand now that the replacement for com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential is now com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials, but I am at a loss on how to use it by passing in a json secret key called from an Azure Key Vault so that I can return the JWT. Here is what I've built so far, calling Azure Function key vault and returning the Google .json secret file associated with my Service Account. I receive a 500 return message because I am not appropriately call the JWT in my response. I'm referencing [this part of Google auth library for java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) & it's not working. Any tips to tweak my code???

```
 package GetOAuthFunction;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.gson.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger, getting value from Key Vault, returning Google Analytics Access Token in get request return body
 */
public class HttpKeyVaultFunc {
    @FunctionName("GetGoogleAnalyticsOAuthToken")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req", 
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, 
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        String secret = System.getenv("KEY_VAULT_URL");
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(secret)
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();
        
        KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = secretClient.getSecret("clientsecret");
        
        String clientsecretvalue = retrievedSecret.getValue();
        JsonObject clientsecretarray = new Gson().fromJson(clientsecretvalue, JsonObject.class);
       GoogleCredentials credentials =  GoogleCredentials.fromStream(clientsecretarray).createScoped(new String {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"}) ;
 
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatusOK).body("Access Token: "+ credentials.getAccessToken().build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the [Google Auth Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) contains the necessary classes required to authenticate against Google services.

Please, consider read the documentation of the API when describing [Explicit credential loading](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java#explicit-credential-loading):

> To get Credentials from a Service Account JSON key use
> `GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream)` or
> `GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream, HttpTransportFactory)`. Note
> that the credentials must be refreshed before the access token is
> available.
>
> ```java
> GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new 
> FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
> credentials.refreshIfExpired();
> AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
> // OR
> AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
> ```

In your code, assuming your Azure Key Vault contains the service account credentials in JSON format, you could try something like the following:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.gson.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger, getting value from Key Vault, returning Google Analytics Access Token in get request return body
 */
public class HttpKeyVaultFunc {
    @FunctionName("GetGoogleAnalyticsOAuthToken")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req", 
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, 
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        String secret = System.getenv("KEY_VAULT_URL");
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(secret)
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();
        
        KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = secretClient.getSecret("clientsecret");
        
        String clientSecretValue = retrievedSecret.getValue();
        byte[] clientSecretValueBytes = null;
        
        try {
            clientSecretValueBytes = clientSecretValue.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException use) {
            clientSecretValueBytes = clientSecretValue.getBytes();   
        }

        InputStream clientSecretValueStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(clientSecretValueBytes);

        GoogleCredentials credentials =  GoogleCredentials.fromStream(clientSecretValueStream)
            .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly") ;
        credentials.refreshIfExpired();
        AccessToken accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();
 
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatusOK)
          .body("Access Token: " + accessToken.getTokenValue())
          .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked like a champ!!! Please accept my 50 point bounty as a small reward for getting me unstuck here. :)

Comment: You are welcome @LeeWhieldon! I am very happy to hear that it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HttpRequestInitializer. This is my example code to work with Google Drive API in Java.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;

// file 1 is the JSON credential file
// GoogleCredential have been deprecated so instead I use HttpRequestInitializer 
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(file1))
        .createScoped(DriveScopes.all()));
Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName(ApplicationName).build();
```

This is the code from Google doc instruction:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .createScoped(DriveScopes.all());

// Construct the drive service object.
return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful! I'd like to only return the access token and not connect to Google Drive API. I see that you are passing credentials directly into the drive builder. What is the method to return the access token?

Comment: @LeeWhieldon As i know the HttpRequestInitializer can be use directly for auth(you can see that in my case i pass in the service account key as paramter) and you can't get access token from it. Maybe what you want is to use the HttpRequestInitializer directly for request. Can you provide more context about what you do with the access token?

Comment: Sure, I want to pass an ephemeral Google Analytics access token into an api call leveraging azure data factory. Thus, I need to return an Access Token to pass into an azure data factory pipeline to substantiate an extract using an azure function to return the access token.

Comment: Also, GoogleCredential in your code is depreciated: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential

Comment: @LeeWhieldon the second code is just code add in to show how I use HttpRequestInitializer to replace GoogleCredential in my case.

Comment: Let me clarify, I need the Java Web Token (JWT), not the user private key. Hopefully that helps clarify...